# What type of terminal is created when creating a pseudoterminal through open_pty()?

Tags: c, linux

> What type of terminal is created when creating a pseudoterminal through open_pty()?

I've wondered how the pseudoterminal opened by `open_pty()` behaves? Is the behavior of the pseudoterminal similar to GNOME terminal in terms of input/output, or what kind of terminal does the pseudoterminal mimicks?

Using a C-program, I've opened a pseudoterminal (after `fork()`) through `open_pty()` and made it a login terminal through `login_pty()`. Then, I've used the `execv()` call to execute `sh` such that the parent and child processes can communicate through the master/slave ends of the pseudoterminal.

In particular, I notice how input to pty is sent to `sh` and how output from `sh` is sent to the stdout of the pty - is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: @hek2mgl - does the terminal has a type like GNOME?

Comment: Probably this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426280/what-do-pty-and-tty-mean ?